# PHP execution may be asynchronous?

Tags: php

I made a little trial using JS upon canvas and images. The final part of it calls a page where at the beginning I try to write upon the server the final image.

The process supposes that a previous file exists, not complete:

```
<?php
$filename = explode(".", $_POST["trans_file"]); // name of the image file
if (!unlink("transit/" . $_POST["trans_file"])) echo "File " . $_POST["trans_file"] . "not found!<br />";       // remove the partial file
$filesave = $filename[0] . ".png";              // I will save a PNG file
$filejpg = $filename[0] . ".jpg";               // but I will transform it into JPG
$data = $_POST["base64img_data"];               // here I receive the base64 image by a previous process
$data = explode(";", $data);                    // I remove the first part of it
$data = explode(",", $data[1]);                 // $data[1] now contains the base64 image complete
$image=base64_decode(chunk_split($data[1]));    // $image is now a PNG file
$handle = fopen("transit/$filesave", "wb");     // Create a PNG file
fwrite($handle, $image);                        // write it
fclose($handle);                                // Close, and transform it into JPG
    png2jpg("transit/$filesave", "transit/$filejpg", 100);
    unlink("transit/$filesave");                // remove PNG image
```

I've put this at the beginning of the page, but the browser always displays the previous file, the one cancelled at the beginning, and being itself a JPG.

Strange enough (for me) this sequence is working perfectly on one server, not working on a different one!

I suppose it could be a case of asynchronous execution of PHP and JS inside the page.

How may I synchronize server and browser?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have permission to write into folder ?

Comment: Probably a cache issue

Comment: Yes the file is on the server: if I click reload the page displays correctly. It looks like to be only late...

Answer (score 0):

what happens if one process writes to the file and in the middle of the operation another process deletes it?

use `.lock` files so only 1 process tries to manipulate the files in question.

Comment: that would be one way to achieve a mutual exclusion, yes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php